# JPA cascade merge does not persist attribute

Tags: java, persistence, cascade, openjpa

I've an entity on OpenJPA 2.0

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "os_wfentry")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "jwe_seq", sequenceName = "jwe_seq", initialValue = 10, allocationSize = 1)
public class JPAWorkflowEntry implements WorkflowEntry, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -755511983025049452L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "jwe_seq")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String workflowName;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private Integer workflowState;

    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "entry")
    private final List<JPACurrentStep> currentSteps;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "entry")
    private final List<JPAHistoryStep> historySteps;

    public JPAWorkflowEntry() {
        currentSteps = new ArrayList<>();
        historySteps = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

...
and on JPACurrent and JPAHistory step I've inserted:

```
@ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "entry_id")
    protected JPAWorkflowEntry entry;
```

It is all correct (in theory); but when I try to save (or update) a new instance of JPAWorkflowStore, having a NOT EMPTY list of (current or history) steps, list of steps attribute is not persistend on db and it always an empty list. Can You help me?? What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false) for your JPACurrent and JPAHistory.

What you have done is @Column(name = "entry_id") i dont see "entry_id" mapping to any cölumn in JPAWorkflowEntry

Comment: mapping is in the one to many relationship `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "entry")`, my error was that I didn't add `@Column` on `currentStep` and `historyStep` attributes of entity `JPAWorkflowEntry`